# No internet in Linux after rebooting from Windows

Tags: linux, internet, multi-boot, gentoo

After **rebooting** from Windows XP to Gentoo Linux, I can't connect to anywhere (internet, others computers, router). Internet is working fine if instead of rebooting I shutdown the PC and then boot properly.

`Ifconfig` shows everything is fine, except no packet are received/transmitted.

```
ping 192.168.9.1
-> Destination Host Unreachable
```

`mtr <ip>` shows nothing, just empty line. Works only on loopback and IP specified in config: `/etc/conf.d/net.eth0`

<strike>IP is assigned automatically via DHCP and by MAC address (so both Linux & Windows have same IP)</strike>
IP is static `192.168.9.3`.

Router used: `Asus WL-500gP` (with Oleg firmware), whole network is `100 Base-T`, IP: `192.168.9.1` MASK: `255.255.255.0`

Windows info:

- NIC: `Realtek RTL8139/810x Family`
- Driver version: `5.719.325.2009`

Linux info:

- DMESG: `8139too  RealTek RTL8139`
- Kernel built-in driver: `RealTek RTL-8129/8130/8139 PCI Fast Ethernet Adapter`
- Kernel version `3.5.7` & latest `3.7.4` (gentoo-sources)

The LEDs on NIC blink only in Windows, remain black even during POST.

Comment: `ping`? `mtr`? `dig`? What have you tried? Please be more specific than "No internet".

Comment: Tried pinging my router, from router to workstation, from another workstation etc.. I will update.

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but what happens if you bring the interface down and back up? Do you have the dhcp service enabled in Linux?

Comment: I tried it too. `/etc/init.d/net.eth0 restart` works, except `sshd` won't start.

Comment: @A.D.: If that fixes it, it sounds like a firmware / driver problem; dmesg might report about this.

Comment: @TomWijsman no, it says `[ok]` for everything (bringing up interfaces) but connection isn't working.

Comment: It sounds like your DHCP client is not waiting long enough for the link to come up. Precisely what is this machine connected to? A switch or a router? If a switch, is it managed? If so, how is it configured? Is it running spanning tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is my friend. Thanks goes to [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10863595&postcount=18) and marvelous [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Configuration#Realtek_no_link_.2F_WOL_issue):

> Users with Realtek 8168 8169 8101 8111(C) based NICs (cards / and on-board) may notice an issue where the NIC seems to be disabled on boot and has no Link light. This can usually be found on a dual boot system where Windows is also installed. It seems that using the offical Realtek drivers (dated anything after May 2007) under Windows is the cause. These newer drivers disable the Wake-On-LAN feature by disabling the NIC at Windows shutdown time, where it will remain disabled until the next time Windows boots. You will be able to notice if this issue is affecting you if the Link light remains off until Windows boots up; during Windows shutdown the Link light will switch off. Normal operation should be that the link light is always on as long as the system is on, even during POST. This issue will also affect other operative systems without newer drivers (eg. Live CDs).

Possible solutions:

1. Rollback/change Windows driver
2. Enable WOL in Windows driver
3. Newer Realtek Linux driver
4. Enable LAN Boot ROM in BIOS/CMOS

I tried 2nd one which works. 4th did not (MB is some old EPoX).

To Enable WOL hit <kbd>WIN</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> -> `devmgmt.msc` -> double-click your NIC -> On Advanced Tab set **Shutdown Wake-On-Lan** to `Enabled`. REBOOT!

[image]

If you are interested, bug is filled here: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53521

Comment: @TomWijsman I'll file this bug tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

What kernel version are you using? I'd try using the latest stable point release of the Linux kernel, at the very least.

My initial insight into this is that it's likely a bug where Windows "does something" to the hardware, which is not properly reset on a regular reboot, but **is** reset during a full power off. Whatever Windows does is incompatible with the way the `8139too` driver works.

Using the latest kernel version will reduce the possibility that there is a bug which has already been fixed. If the latest kernel version doesn't resolve the bug, I would include the following in an email to LKML (the Linux Kernel Mailing List) or at least to the Gentoo developers:

- Output of `lspci -nnvv`
- Output of `dmesg` on a cold boot where ethernet works
- Output of `dmesg` on a reboot from Windows

Comment: Yes, I have to discover what does that. What version of kernel "is" latest? I'm using 3.5.7.

Comment: @A.D.: 3.5.7 is latest Gentoo x86 stable, 3.6.11 is latest Gentoo AMD64 stable, 3.7.4 is latest Gentoo unstable; 3.7.6 is is latest upstream stable, 3.8-rc6 is mainline and can be considered the latest upstream unstable. I would suggest you to try =sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-3.7.4 as well as trying out the latest sys-kernel/git-sources. I don't see a relevant fix in the logs; so, if you still experience this please try to capture the information requested here and file it at http://bugs.gentoo.org/. I'm doing bug wrangling as well as kernel bug wrangling there and will follow up on you... :)

Comment: @TomWijsman will try. I'll google for now, because it must be something in Windows.

Comment: Kernel updated to `3.7.4` no change.